# Error when removing a line from a .txt file

Tags: python

Working on a guess who game at school and cant find a way to remove a line from a .txt fie. I keep getting the following error:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='characters.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='characters.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='characters.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Here is the code:

```
information = open("characters.txt","r")

hair = input("Does your character have black hair?") #Asks for input under variable name hair
if hair == "yes":
    for line in lines: #Breaks it down into individual lines
        if line.split(',')[1] == "Black hair":          
           lines.remove(line) 
        print(information)
```

Comment: That does not look like an error message at all. How and where do you calculate the value of the variable `information`? Please edit your question to include all relevant information (and remove irrelevant information, as the case may be).

Comment: Okay I have finally fixed it but now it skips one line so does not remove. So for example if there was a Brown hair on top of another brown hair in the .txt file then it would only remove one of them?

Comment: Accept one of the answers here (post one of your own if you don't like the others and explain how you fixed it). Post a new question with your new code and your new problem. Include a link to this one for background.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error.  It is a string representation of an open file object:

```
>>> open('a.txt')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='a.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
>>>
```

If you want to print the contents of this file, you will need to call its `read` method:

```
print(information.read())
```

The `read` method will read all of the file's contents into a string.  If you only want one line however, use the `readline` method.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to print `information` but it's not entirely clear what you do want to print.

```
features = dict()
with open("characters.txt","r") as information:
    for line in information:
        _, haircolor = line.split(',')
        features[haircolor] = line

hair = input("Does your character have black hair?")
if hair == "yes":
    for entry in features['Black hair']:
        print 'Character could be {}'.format(entry)
```

Maybe at this point you would want to ask another question in order to reduce the remaining entries based on some other distinguishing feature.  You should probably design your main loop as a loop over features you want to ask about, rather than create a long, repetitive program which asks for one feature at a time.  When you are left with one entry, you can stop looping (or if you end up with zero entries, you failed to guess).

For what it's worth, your feature representation appears less than optimal, but since you are not describing it, this is just a quick impression.  (You could get better answers if you described the pertinent parts of the program at least briefly.)